# setting name of an HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is some code that is resulting in failure to set the class for each li in a group of li tags:

```js
function pathContents(fileList)
{
 var $list = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {
  $('<li/>').prop('class', 'test123');
  $('<li/>').text(file).appendTo($list);
    });
    return $list;
}
```

When I open the Inspector in Firefox, right click on one of the li's, and choose 'Show DOM Properties' the className property shows empty string:
[image]

Since there is a CSS rule for the class test123 that says to make the font blue, and the font is still black, it appears that this line of code is not assigning a class of 'test123' to the li tags.  I have also tried `$('<li/>').attr('class', 'test123');` which has given the exact same result as when trying to use .prop().  Why aren't these working?

Comment: Your first `$('<li/>')` is just creating an `li`, setting the class and then doing nothing else with it, ie not adding it to the `document`

Comment: `.setAttribute("name", "Joe");`   If you want to add class use `.classList.add('Joe');`  no jQuery necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `addClass()` instead of `prop()`

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

And you are creating two different list items and only appending one of them.

```
$('<li/>').prop('class', 'test123');
$('<li/>').text(file).appendTo($list);
```

You can save try

```
$('<li/>').addClass('test123').text(file).appendTo(list);
```

Comment: Yes!  The last line of code works.  However, there are properties that need to be added to each li as well.  For instance, each li tag needs to have an id property added that equals whatever is in 'file'.  How do properties get added to this code?

Comment: `$('<li/>').addClass('test123').prop('id', file).text(file).appendTo($list);` appears to be adding the id correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function pathContents(fileList)
{
 var $list = $('ul');
    $.each(fileList, function (_, file) {
  $('li').addClass('test123').text(file).appendTo($list);
    });
    return $list;
}
```